# What's the meaning of the second part of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence, conjunctions

> Namespaced functions, unless declared "friend," have no access to the class' internals, ***whereas static methods have***.

What's the meaning of the second part of this sentence, which is seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435105/13611002.

Comment: Static methods have access to the class internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also read it to say,

Namespaced functions, unless declared "friend," have no access to the class' internals, **whereas static methods do have access to the class' internals.**

*Definitions:*

**whereas:** while on the contrary.